# Are "for" and "in exchange of" interchangeable?

Tags: grammar

I am wondering if "for" can mean the same thing as "in exchange of". The reason I am thinking "for" may be wrong is that "for" is a much more general term and can be used in many ways and for some reason it sounds odd to me in some sentences.

Here's an example:

> You convinced your friend to do something crazy for monetary
>   compensation.

"For" sounds weird in this sentence, whereas "in exchange of" sounds ok.

Comment: I have rolled back the edit you made to your question. By editing it, you invalidated both existing answers. At first, I was tempted to downvote one or both because it looked like they hadn't answered your question—but then I saw you edited your question *after* the answers had been given. Please don't make such edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact,

> You convinced your friend to do something crazy for monetary compensation

is perfectly correct, if slightly awkward, while

> You convinced your friend to do something crazy in exchange of  monetary compensation

is simply incorrect.

One could write:

> You convinced your friend to do something crazy in exchange **for** monetary compensation

but the simplest and most natural form is:

> You convinced your friend to do something crazy for money.

The word "for" has many uses. In constructions like "{something} for {another thing}" it may indicate an exchange, or a substitution.

"in exchange of" is not a usual phrase. "in exchange for" is much more common. In fact [This google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+exchange+for%2C+in+exchange+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20exchange%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20exchange%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20exchange%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20exchange%20of%3B%2Cc0) suggests that 
"in exchange of" effectively never occurs, and I cannot think of a sentence where it would be correct and natural.

Answer (score 2):

"We don't say "in exchange of". Did you mean "in exchange **for**"? If so, then you can shorten it to "for" in expressions like these: I work for money; I work in exchange for money; I sing for my supper; I sing in exchange for my supper.